# Why the new keyword has been used directly?

Tags: magento2.3.0

Why the new keyword has been used in `dispatch` method in `\Magento\Framework\Event\Manager` class ?

```
/**
     * Dispatch event
     *
     * Calls all observer callbacks registered for this event
     * and multiple observers matching event name pattern
     *
     * @param string $eventName
     * @param array $data
     * @return void
     */
    public function dispatch($eventName, array $data = [])
    {
        $eventName = mb_strtolower($eventName);
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('EVENT:' . $eventName, ['group' => 'EVENT', 'name' => $eventName]);
        foreach ($this->_eventConfig->getObservers($eventName) as $observerConfig) {
            $event = new \Magento\Framework\Event($data);
            $event->setName($eventName);

            $wrapper = new Observer();
            $wrapper->setData(array_merge(['event' => $event], $data));

            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('OBSERVER:' . $observerConfig['name']);
            $this->_invoker->dispatch($observerConfig, $wrapper);
            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('OBSERVER:' . $observerConfig['name']);
        }
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('EVENT:' . $eventName);
    }
```